# Java GUI - Positioning

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to position two buttons to be on the left top side. They are always in the center top though.

I have tried this:

```
jp = new JPanel();
jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

//c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_TRAILING;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
jp.add(test, c);
c.gridy++;
jp.add(atest, c);
add(jp);
```

But its still at center, not on left side (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHdmZ.png).

[image]

This is an image I took. The red is a scetch of how I wish the buttons to be.

---

Updated:

```
 ArrayList<String> atest = new ArrayList<String>();
    JLabel[ ] asd = new JLabel[100];

    int temp = 0;



GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
atest.add("Hello");
atest.add("haelp");
atest.add("yummy");
atest.add("whats wrong");

for(String server : servers)
{
    asd[temp] = new JLabel();
    asd[temp].setText(server);
    jp.add(asd[temp], c);
    c.weighty++;
    c.gridy++;
    temp++;

}
```

Im trying to read string from array and add it as label one after other on left side.
Doesn't work out too good, here's the result:
http://prntscr.com/26a9rb
If gridbaglayout is bad way of doing it, which way should I go for?

Comment: you can try other layout

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Which one would be the best for this?

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for an explanation of how the contraints work. The section on `weightx, weighty` should solve your problem.

Comment: I think he should change the anchor too to achieve his required layout too :)

Comment: I get this now: http://prntscr.com/26a1mm I use this: GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
 c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;                     I have set weightx/y to 1.0, then gridx/y to 0. For every label I added 1 to gridy, and with weighty i tried adding none, 1, 10000 but It won't line up each after other. Any idea? @Sage

Comment: @HowdoIeditmydisplayname, If you want to have a layout like list of component  where each component will come one after another in row, i don't think GridBagLayout actually will do the job. Please update your question with your current code and try to link an image with current view, so that we can understand.

Comment: @HowdoIeditmydisplayname, You could make use of `BoxLayout` look into my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you can use a plugin called WindowBuilder to build the frames:

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

You have to apply spring layout to your window in WindowBuilder to drag and drop buttons from the toolbar like in the .NET designer in VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem:

1. set the `weightx` and `weighty` of `GridBagConstraint` to some other value than `0` as @camickr mentioned.
2. you should set the `anchor` to [`FIRST_LINE_START`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#FIRST_LINE_START). The [`WEST`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#WEST) anchor will put the component on the left side of its display area but the components will be *centered vertically*. It is equivalent to `LINE_START` for horizontal, left-to-right orientations of components

**Edit:**

Try to look into the `BoxLayout`. Cleaver use of `preferredSize` with alignment setting can achieve what you are expecting. I have written a SSCCE for you. However, reading about the [**size behavior with BoxLayout**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#size) will help you understand the example better.

[image]

```
class AComponent extends JPanel
{

    public AComponent(Color c) {

        setBackground(c);
        setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    }


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        return new Dimension(200,  100);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(getPreferredSize());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize();
        return new Dimension(200, dim.height);
    }

}



class MyWindow extends JFrame
{

    public MyWindow ()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel container = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(300, 350);
                }
        };

        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        container.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        container.add(new AComponent(new Color(0xFFAA00)));
        container.add(new AComponent(new Color(0x359DBD)));
        container.add(new AComponent(new Color(0xFFD47E)));

        add(container);

        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
               new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set jp like this:  jp.setLayout(null);